# Select query in multi primary key table

Tags: mysql

I'm making a database with fitness exercises and their equipment needed.

My database is designed like this

`+-------+-----------------+
| id(pk)|    equip(pk)    |
+-------+-----------------+
|  1    | Barbell         |
|  1    | Bench           |
|  2    | Dumbbell        |
|  2    | Bench           |
|  3    | Barbell         |
|  4    | Dumbbell        |
| ...   | ..(many rows).. |
+-------+-----------------+`

The id stands for a certain exercise and the equip is needed to select that exercise

So for exercise 1 (id = 1) you need a Barbell and Bench.
But for exercise 3 (id = 3) you only need a Barbell

So if the user want exercises containing Barbell and Bench, id 1 and 3 should be selected

---

Current Query

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(equip SEPARATOR ', ') equip
FROM equip group by id ) as x
```

This gives the following result

`+-------+-----------------+
| id(pk)|    equip(pk)    |
+-------+-----------------+
|  1    | Barbell, Bench  |
|  2    | Dumbbell, Bench |
|  3    | Barbell         |
|  4    | Dumbbell        |
| ...   | ..(many rows).. |
+-------+-----------------+`

So if i want to search for Barbell and Bench, 1 and 3 should be selected
*Thank you very much :)*

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than explaining your expected outcome, just explain the business rules you're trying to implement and give us some insight into the environment you're working in.

Also, what do you mean by "barbell and bench are true"?  Varchar fields cannot be true or false.

For instance, your last line talks about weights and support, which are not included in your data set and would probably help in answering the question.  Because I don't have rep to comment, I had to create an answer, so here is my best shot without more information:

```
select * from (
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(equip SEPARATOR ', ') concatenatedEquip
FROM table GROUP BY id )
where (concatenatedEquip contains('Barbell') or concatenatedEquip 
contains('Bench'))
```

so this query would

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, your query helped a little bit, i changed my question, i hope it is clear now.